# ASP.NET MVC: How to use multiple models in one View?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have the following ViewModel that includes 2 other models:

```
public class ViewModel
{
   public ViewModel1 viewModel1 { get; set; }
   public ViewModel2 viewModel2 { get; set; }
}
```

My View looks like this:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.viewModel1.NameOfCustomer)
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.viewModel2.ProductCategory)
```

And finally the controller:

```
public ActionResult CreateNewOrder(ViewModel viewModel)
{

  Model1 myModel1 = new Model1()
  {
    NameOfCustomer = viewModel.viewModel1.NameOfCustomer
  };

  db.Orders.Add(myModel1);
  db.SaveChanges();

  return View(viewModel);
}
```

The problem is, if I want to take the data from my ViewModel to pass it to my actual model, it does not work. It just shows null as value. If I do the following change to my controller data is there but this does not work as it should:

```
public ActionResult CreateNewOrder(ViewModel viewModel)
{
  // that works
  viewModel.viewModel1.NameOfCustomer = "John John";

  Model1 myModel1 = new Model1()
  {
    myModel1.NameOfCustomer = viewModel.viewModel1.NameOfCustomer
  };

  db.Orders.Add(myModel1);
  db.SaveChanges();

  return View(viewModel);
}
```

So I guess the problem is, my data from my view is not being send correctly to my ViewModel. I hope you guys can give me a hint what Im doing wrong.

Regards,

Comment: When you say "It just shows null as value. " Specify what shows null? Is the viewModel null or the model itself's properties are null?

Comment: You can post your different ViewModel data to different Actions. Like `ViewModel1` data to some action `/vm1` and `ViewModel2` to action `/vm2`

Comment: You can use tuple to send multiple model to a view

Comment: @bharatpatidar, OP is editing data and your cannot use `Tuple`!

Comment: Tee See: The viewModel.viewModel1.NameOfCustomer property of the ViewModel is null, thats why my guess is, something is not being send correctly from my view to my Controller.

Comment: @RawMVC, If its `null` it suggests that `NameOfCustomer` is a field, not a property (the code you have shown works fine)

Comment: Show us both your classes - ViewModel1 and ViewModel2

Comment: public class ViewModel1
{
  public string NameOfCustomer{get; set;}
}

public class ViewModel2
{
  public string ProductCategory{get; set;}
}

Comment: Are there any warnings reported when you build?

Comment: Also, please can you expand you code examples (it's best to edit your question) so that we can see namespaces and add in the Razer view too. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**Edited** following @Stephen Muecke's comment, doesn't sound like this is the case. However, I'll leave this answer here, as my first port of call would still be to check out the POST payload in the request to make sure it was going across the wire as expected, so this part may be useful

---

It looks like it's because the data coming into your MVC action, is essentially a flattened view model, whereas the model expected in the action is hierarchical.

If look at the network tab within your browser's dev tools, find the POST request being made, and check the payload being sent to the server.

Sounds like this is being posted:
`{"NameOfCustomer": "SomePerson", ....}`

Which won't be autobinding server-side to your model, because `ViewModel` does not itself have a NameOfCustomer property - instead, it's on a child object held in the `viewModel1` property. So, autobinding would work if the following was being posted:
`{"viewModel1": {"NameOfCustomer" : "SomePerson", ....}}`

Solutions include:
1) construct the payload to post from JS yourself, ensuring the structure reflects the nested objects correctly as above
2) Create a flattened viewmodel, so all properties from ViewModel1 are held directly at top level in the `ViewModel` class
3) Create a custom model binder

Comment: `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.viewModel1.NameOfCustomer)` generates an input with `name="viewModel1.NameOfCustomer"` which will bind correctly

Comment: @StephenMuecke - Thanks, seemed like something odd was going on with the model binding in that area, but perhaps not!

Answer (score 0):

Your code should properly carry the information to the controller(see a similar fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/gHdWhZ))

The piece:

```
Model1 myModel1 = new Model1()
  {
    NameOfCustomer = viewModel.viewModel1.NameOfCustomer
  };

  db.Orders.Add(myModel1);
  db.SaveChanges();
```

Are you sure you are doing the right thing here? You are creating a `Model1` type variable and add it to the `Orders` in your database. Are you getting any errors? Maybe the right code should be something like:

```
      Order myModel1 = new Order ()
      {
        NameOfCustomer = viewModel.viewModel1.NameOfCustomer
      };

      db.Orders.Add(myModel1);
      db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, the error is with MVC not binding to the action parameter, not what is being saved by the database.

Comment: Model1 is maybe not the best way to name it, you are right. But the its the right model. I will answer the rest of your question if im back at home, till now, I want to thank everyone for his effort here, im really thankful for all your feedback! :)

Comment: i just had to ask/assume that, because in the fiddle link everything seems to work fine with the binding. Also RawMVC stated something like "If I do the following change to my controller data is there but this does not work as it should", words that made me believe that the data was still not saving to the database.