# ASP.NET MVC: Using multiple viewModels and how to pass the data correct to the model?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, model-view-controller

based on my last [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39701160/asp-net-mvc-how-to-use-multiple-models-in-one-view) and the answers I got, I was thinking about them and what was the real problem with my application. And I think you guys helped me to figure it out with all you wrote there, really thankful for that. So I made a small but working example to demonstrate my problem:

My model:

```
public class Order
    {
        public int OrderID { get; set; }
        public string NameOfCustomer { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
    }
```

The ViewModel that contains the 2 other ViewModels I need:

```
public class ViewModelOrder
    {
        public ViewModelSendItNow viewModelSenditNow { get; set; }
        public ViewModelSafeForLater viewModelSafeForLater { get; set; }
    }
```

The ViewModel SendItNow:

```
public class ViewModelSendItNow
    {
        [Required]
        public string NameOfCustomer { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Address { get; set; }
    }
```

The ViewModel SafeForLater:

```
public class ViewModelSafeForLater
    {
        public string NameOfCustomer { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
    }
```

The View:

```
@model ProblemExample.Models.ViewModelOrder

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "CreateOrder";
}

<h2>CreateOrder</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

        @if (Request.Form["SafeForLater"] != null)
        {
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.viewModelSafeForLater.NameOfCustomer)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.viewModelSafeForLater.Address)
        }

        else
        {
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.viewModelSenditNow.NameOfCustomer)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.viewModelSenditNow.Address)
        }
        <hr />
        <button class="formular-button-submit" type="submit" name="SenditNow">Send it now!</button>
        <button class="formular-button-submit" type="submit" name="SafeForLater">Safe it for later!</button>
    </div>
}

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

The controller:

```
public ActionResult CreateOrder()
        {
            ViewModelOrder viewModel = new ViewModelOrder();
            return View(viewModel);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult CreateOrder(ViewModelOrder viewModel)
        {
            if (Request.Form["SafeForLater"] != null)
            {
                Order myOrder = new Order()
                {
                    NameOfCustomer = viewModel.viewModelSafeForLater.NameOfCustomer,
                    Address = viewModel.viewModelSafeForLater.Address
                };
                db.Orders.Add(myOrder);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }

            else
            {
                Order myOrder = new Order()
                {
                    NameOfCustomer = viewModel.viewModelSenditNow.NameOfCustomer,
                    Address = viewModel.viewModelSenditNow.Address
                };
                db.Orders.Add(myOrder);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            return View(viewModel);
        }
```

So, the user should see a form and when he decides to send it now, validation should jump in and if he wants to save it for later, no validation should be done. Thats why I try to do that with the 2 buttons in the view. The problem is, the example works for send it now, it gets saved in the database like it should, but when I hit the button Safe for later, I get a Nullreference Exception and I don't really know why. So maybe you guys see the mistake in my code and give me a hint how I could solve this or what I could try.

Regards,

Comment: You code does not make sense. When the view is first rendered you always hit the `else` block and you generate form controls for `viewModelSenditNow` (so validation will always kick in). Then in the POST method, `Request.Form["SafeForLater"]` will always be `null` because your submit buttons to not have a `value` attribute and therefore do not post back a value. And why are you then returning the view anyway?

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks for your answer. Can I ask you one thing, just in words, how would you try to solve this? Is there anything from the concept point of view I missed completely out to do something like that?

Comment: Your have not given enough info to explain what you wanting to do, but best guess is to use a single view model that includes a `bool SaveAsDraft` property, and apply a [foolproof](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/) `[RequiredIfFalse("SaveAsDraft")]` to the other properties (and probably reconfigure the `$.validator` to only validate on submit). Then if the user wants to save a 'Draft' which may not be valid, they can check the checkbox generated by `@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.SaveAsDraft)`.

Comment: You only need one submit button and then in the POST method, you can also check the value of `SaveAsDraft`, and if its `true`, you should be saving it to another table in the DB so that the main table can have constraints applied (although that bit is really up to you - if you did have only one table, then all your fields would need to allow `NULL`)

Comment: Thanks once again for your effort, I will try to explain what the whole idea is. So the user has a form like above and he should be able to do 2 things, 

1)Send an complete order(validation should jump in) 

2)If he decides to do send the complete order later (no validation at this point), he should be able to save it for later and edit again.

But I want to keep all that in one View so later hes able to easily switch between the real order and what he wants to save for later.

I hope now the idea is clear, if not, feel free to ask what is not clear and I will try to answer it.

Comment: That is also the reason why I was using two buttons, one to show he can send it now and the other one if he wants just save it for later.

Comment: Sorry, but having 2 buttons makes no sense at all, and you certainly cannot get any validation with your current implementation. Instead of 2 buttons, just use a checkbox to let the user decide if they want to save a 'Draft' or the 'Final' with one submit button.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simply because you render only 2 text boxes when the page loads, so only two text boxes will get rendered at a time which is the send it now because it appears that `Request.Form["SafeForLater"]` is empty so, the code moves to the else block and renders only the send it now text boxes.

You should render both and only hide/show them using css.
so your code should be like this:

```
@model ProblemExample.Models.ViewModelOrder

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "CreateOrder";
}

<h2>CreateOrder</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

        @if (Request.Form["SafeForLater"] != null)
        {
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.viewModelSafeForLater.NameOfCustomer)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.viewModelSafeForLater.Address)
            <div style="display:none">
               @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.viewModelSenditNow.NameOfCustomer)
               @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.viewModelSenditNow.Address)
            </div>
        }

        else
        {
            <div style="display:none">
               @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.viewModelSafeForLater.NameOfCustomer)
               @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.viewModelSafeForLater.Address)
            </div>

            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.viewModelSenditNow.NameOfCustomer)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.viewModelSenditNow.Address)
        }
        <hr />
        <button class="formular-button-submit" type="submit" name="SenditNow">Send it now!</button>
        <button class="formular-button-submit" type="submit" name="SafeForLater">Safe it for later!</button>
    </div>
}

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Comment: Hi @Haitham Shaddad,

thanks for your answer, I did try your solution, it solves the error with Nullreference, but yet the value for Safe It for Later is not saved to the database, it just shows null

Comment: Did you debug and inspect the values in the action? can you confirm that the values are bind to the model inside the controller action? just to know if it is a data binding issue or saving to the database issue

Comment: I did a step after step debugging and the values seem not be bind to the model, in the model both values are null.

Comment: Can you inspect the posted values by click F12 in the browser, check the network tab and click the submit button, then check the request and see what the Request body contains? Also can you show us the generated HTML in the browser?

Comment: So another strange thing is, if I try to save it for later, and click the button in both textboxes the text is gone. If i do that for send it now, the text is still there, so it must be a problem with the binding to the model...

Comment: put the generated HTML and the post values here in order to know what is being sent to the server